# Is it possible it get a .xib window to a tabbed storyboard

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.2, storyboard, uipickerview, xib

i have not long bin doing code, Xcode so I'm a little rubbish basically i have created a .xib and would like it to be in a storyboard but i really don't have a glue where to start because i have a xib window that has `UITableView` and `UIPickerView` in it and all the code is fine in the xib but do i need to add code in the storyboard .h / .m etc and is it possible if not how can i do some kind of drop down menu for my app. Heres the code in the xib

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface myview : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>    


    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView* pickerView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* tableData;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* pickerData;


    @end
```

This is the .m but i will break it up

```
    #import "myview.h"

    @implementation myview


    @synthesize tableView, pickerView, tableData, pickerData;





    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

this is the -(void)viewDidLoad];etc..


    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];

        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        pickerView.delegate = self;
        pickerView.dataSource = self;

        tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // table starts empty
        pickerData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil]; // picker starts with values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

        [tableView reloadData];
        [pickerView reloadAllComponents];    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

-(bool) 


        - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
        {
            // Return YES for supported orientations
            return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
        }


        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {
            //The number of sections in UITableView
            return 1;

        }


        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            // The number of rows in the UITableView
            return [tableData count];

        }


         - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
                static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [ [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

          }
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;

    }  


        - (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            // Whatever happens when you select a table view row.
        }

        - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        {
            // The number of sections in the UIPickerView
            return 1;
        }

        - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {
            // The number of rows in the UIPickerView
            return [pickerData count];
        }

        - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {
            // The data for each row in the UIPickerView
            return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
        {
            // whatever you want to happen when a row is selected.

            // here I am assuming you want to remove from the picker and add to the table on selection
            [tableData addObject:[pickerData objectAtIndex:row]];
            [pickerData removeObjectAtIndex:row];

            [tableView reloadData];
            [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];   
     }




        @end
```

i hope all this has made sense and i will look forward to hear from you

thanks so much for your time :)

Comment: Sorry i did try to upload some images but i wouldn't let me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no drop down menu automatic conversion. The process is manual, and is described below:

1. Cut and paste from the xib to the a new storyboard view controller (open up the xib, select all and select copy, then go to storyboard and paste it into a empty view controller).
2. Add a fresh view controller subclass (.m and .h) to the project.
3. Cut and paste the custom method from the old view controller subclass to the new view controller subclass. Be careful not to migrate the code that loads the xib.
4. First associate the new custom view controller subclass with the view controller in storyboard.
5. Hook up all the IBActions and IBOutlets and you should be good to go!
6. Optionally, you can look for ways to use segues instead of IBActions.

Comment: hi i really really appreciate the help but i can't seem to understand this I'm not the best person with Xcode is there any chance you can add in some code and step by step images or something :)

Comment: For the basics, I recommend http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials. Go to the section on "iOS 5 Tutorials".

Comment: hi erm i understand storyboards abit more now its just the xib file still not sure how to get in in the storyboard buddy

Comment: @Paulmasters, open up the xib, select all and select copy, then go to storyboard and paste it into a empty view controller.

Comment: Back to Ray Wenderlich. He covers that in storyboards part 1.