# Can we use xib file in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard

Actually I have two question related to storyboard,

1. Whether I can reuse my xib file which I have created earlier in
   Storyboard as it is or I have to copy contains from xib to
       storyboard?If yes then how?
2. Can I use both storyboard and xib in single project or if I am using storyboard I cannot use xib to create
   viewcontroller?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411324/is-it-possible-it-get-a-xib-window-to-a-tabbed-storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboard and nib files can be used in the same project without issue.  You can instantiate a VC with nib name just as easily with a storyboard based VC as you can otherwise.  The one piece of advice I would give you is if feasible, convert nibs over to storyboard just so the app is easier to manage later on.  If you have a legacy app with several nibs, this might not be very time effective, but if you have only a small number (less than 5 I would say), I would make the time investment to have them all in a single storyboard.